# How can one mute Zoom on iPad?

Tags: ipad, sound-volume, zoom.app

How can one mute [Zoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoom_Video_Communications) on iPad? Turning down the volume doesn't work. I don't mean muting the microphone but muting the other interlocutors.

I am an attendee. I just want to mute the others for myself, but I still want them to hear each other.

[image]

Comment: Are you the host of the meeting or just an attendee?

Comment: @fsb I am an attendee. I just want to mute the others for myself, but I still want them to  hear each other.

Comment: You can leave the audio session. This will disconnect the sound from your device entirely. I don't know exactly where the button is on mobile, but it'll be in the Zoom interface.

Comment: Have a look at: [How to Mute Yourself on a Zoom Call](https://www.howtogeek.com/670311/how-to-mute-yourself-on-a-zoom-call/)

Comment: @EzekielElin thanks good point, looks like a good solution

Comment: @user3439894 thanks, I also want to mute the others for myself, (and I still want them to hear each other).

Comment: As an attendee, I believe the only person you can mute is yourself.  If you do not want to hear the others, then you'll probably have to mute your system's output volume.

Comment: @user3439894 "you'll probably have to mute your system's output volume" -> doesn't work, that's the issue.

Comment: Since Zoom updates their app routinely - adding the version in play may help track if/when the vendor changes this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be done on purpose. However, it is possible to use a workaround:

1. Tap on `More` in the top right corner.
2. Select the option "Disconnect Audio" which is written in red.

To re-establish the connection, tap the icon in the upper right area on the far left named `Join Audio`.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why they would do this on purpose?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I was wondering the same. My guess is, that during development they didn't think of video calls with a great number of participants as we have them now during the pandemic and in which you may decide to do something else while not leaving the call. Instead they probably wanted people to be responsive even when having the app in the background.

Comment: Zoom iOS app is very hostile to the native experience. Since they don't use system API/SDK correctly for sound processing, all sorts of accommodations / accessibility / flexibility are broken. Airplay won't work if the host disables these when they set up the meeting. Other functions will just not work until the app adopts the correct API to enable the features that are possible.

Comment: Why is it even _possible_ to do this?  I'd like my iPad to have more control over the output volume than any individual app.